# How can you "push" files to Google Compute Engine without "Permission denied error"

Tags: debian, file-permissions, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to push files from my computer up to my instance in the cloud with Google Compute Engine. However, whenever I try this command:

`gcutil --project=<project-id> push <instance-name> <local-file> <remote-target-path>`

The problem is that (it appears on the server side) the attempt to push files is denied. Here is the message:

`scp: /Uploads: Permission denied`

where in my case, /Uploads is a directory on the server that I created. I tried using different permission types like 777 and a few others, but could this be related to this comment on the quick start guide for GCE?

"...push does not allow you to save in a directory that requires root permissions, which is necessary in this scenario because the default location above for web server files requires root permissions. You can change the default location to somewhere that doesn't require root access, or open the existing file for edit as root."

I have not edited any permissions other than that directory so I figure it might be an issue as I am most likely using the root account by default. The machine is Debian 7 based

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being that the `/upload` file had to be specified as `upload` without any slashes on either side. It was attempting to upload a directory to an existing directory.

Comment: Good to hear that you've solved your problem! Please [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) so that this question is marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I have just gave this a try. (gce debian)

- Created a directory in the root level called /upload (sudo mkdir upload)
- Changed the permission to 777 (sudo chmod 777, but ownership is still root:root)
- gcutil push local file to remote /upload directory

and it works fine without permission problem. 
Try checking:

- The instance allowed port, by default it should have port 22 opened for ssh. (check from console developer/browser)
- As a non-root user, are you able to create a file in the directory? when you gcutil ssh you should be logged in as a non-root user by default.
- Your user permission for the gce instance.

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi, I assume you ssh and created upload dir and created test files within the directory using the same user? if you try running "gcutil getinstance <instance-name> --print_json --project=<project-id>" are you getting the service account that you would expect ? cheers